ModelForm with field depending on user permission?
I have a model Address with a field and a ModelForm.
class Address(Model):
    number = PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = "__all__"

How do I add a validator to it, when the form is shown to a user with a specific permission? The form should behave as if the model itself would have a number field like this:
number = PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)])

By that I mean that the form should only allow values from 0 to 100, and the backend should validate that the value is inbetween 0 and 100.
The view could pass whether or not to use the limited field like so:
form = AddressForm(enable_limit=True)

And I could do something like this:
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, enable_limit=False, **kwargs):
        if enable_limit:
            self.base_fields["number"].widget.attrs["max"] = 100

However, this only updates the widget. The form does complain about values > 100, but that's only the HTML forms client-side validation and by changing the value in the request, I can go around that, which is not what I want.
Basically, I want to tell the ModelForm to use the Adresse.number field as the foundation, but with an additional MaxValueValidator(100).
How would you solve this?

You can add this as validator as well:
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator


class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, enable_limit=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if enable_limit:
            self.fields['number'].validators.append(MaxValueValidator(100))
            self.fields['number'].widget.attrs['max'] = 100
I would not work with the .base_fields [Django-doc] since that changes the "parent" that spans all the real fields from this form. This thus means that if at a certain moment you use enable_limit, it will from now on add the validator to all AddressForms that are created after that.

This does not work: 'AddressForm' object has no attribute 'fields'. And I'd prefer to add the validator before the widget is created, so the widget is created according to the field and not separate of the field.

@Daniel: you first need to make a super().__init__ call :)

Thanks, I had my super() at the end. Where on when exactly is the form field derived from the model field? As I said, I do much prefer if I could change just the model field for that e.g., number.validators.append(MaxValueValidator(100)), so that the form field AND the widget have that. It's not about adding just one line less, it's more about: when I change the original model field, these things get inherited to my AddressForm.

@Daniel: well a model is request-unaware by design, so that means it does not know anything about the request and the logged in user. Essentially that is the task of a form: processing requests.

But the form is, and it takes a model field, so I should be able to alter that. Where does this happen?

@Daniel: yes, you take the model field, but by altering the model field, that would mean now all models include this validation. It is essentially the global state antipattern then.
